# How Make each app use diffrent database(all sqlite)?

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-database

My project have 3 apps(accounts, books, publishers), And I want each app use its own db but I don't know how :(

( all sqlite but diffrent database)

This is my setting Database part:

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
       'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'publisher_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'publisher_db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'books_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'books_db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'accounts_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'accounts_db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **configure** separate **database setting** in **database** **dictionary**. You mentioned `books` and `publishers` using **postgresql**.

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'accounts': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'users.sqlite3',
    },
    'books': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'book_data',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    },
    'publishers': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'publisher_data',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
 }
```

Comment: What if I just use sqlite instead of postgresql?